# While migrating from tomcat5.5 to tomcat7 the following jsp error is occurring

Tags: java, tomcat7

I am trying to migrate my application to use tomcat7 instead of tomcat5.5 but getting the below error. I am using tomcat-7.0.27 for Window 32 bit machine:

Jun 29, 2012 3:01:05 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded
JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Comment: I didnt get you. Could you please elaborate if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the jar files to skip when scanning for TLDs. This is done in conf/catalina.properties
This will make the error (which obviously is only a INFO message) disapear and speedup the startupd/compile process of your application.